# How to automatically skip callbacks in all unit tests but not in any integration tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, callback

I use Rspec for testing under Rails 4.

I'd like to configure Rspec so that all my unit tests automatically run without callbacks, but all my integration tests run as Rails intended -- with all the same callbacks as you get in production and development.

Is this possible?

I can think of long-winded solution that involve writing conditional logic into my actual callbacks, but not elegant solutions that involve configuring Rspec.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your callback methods with test doubles when your unit tests run, as described in https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/message-expectations/allow-a-message-on-any-instance-of-a-class

For example, if you had the following class:

```
def Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :my_callback

  ...

end
```

you could stub the callback as follows:

```
allow_any_instance_of(Foo).to receive(:my_callback)
```

Comment: Thanks for writing. However, it's not clear to me how this disables callbacks in my unit tests.

Comment: @steven_noble The body of any callback method you stub with `allow` or `expect` will not be called, so the stubbing effectively disables the callback.